# error persmission denied depoying a google cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-authentication, gitlab-ci-runner

I am working with google cloud functions ( runtime python) and I am deploying it using gitlab CI Runner. Unfortunately when I Launch the deploy stage I got an error :

Below is the code I wrote for the runner:

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: google/cloud-sdk
  script:
    - apt-get update && apt-get --only-upgrade install kubectl google-cloud-sdk
    - apt-get install google-cloud-sdk
    - gcloud init
    - gcloud config set project $GCP_PROJECT_ID
    - gcloud config list
    - gcloud beta functions deploy ${FUNCTION_NAME} --memory ${MEMORY} --region ${REGION} --stage-bucket ${STAGE_BUCKET}  --runtime ${RUNTIME} --trigger-http

  <<: *tags_rlt
```

I get the following output:

```
$ gcloud config list
[component_manager]
disable_update_check = true
[core]
account = dfr-frer0gr-mdef0nsa@rdfrd.iam.gserviceaccount.com
disable_usage_reporting = true
project = rdfrd
[metrics]
environment = github_docker_image

Your active configuration is: [default]
$ gcloud beta functions deploy ${FUNCTION_NAME} --memory ${MEMORY} --region ${REGION} --stage-bucket ${STAGE_BUCKET}  --runtime ${RUNTIME} --trigger-http
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[403], code=[Forbidden], message=[The caller does not have permission]
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

Any idea how to fix this please

Comment: What roles does the service account have? It should have Cloud Functions Developer and Service Account User roles, as per [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/iam#troubleshooting_permission_errors). I also recommend you 'obscure' the service account that you have inputted here, just in case.

Comment: yes I changed the service account to a "fake" value , thanks for mentioning this.

Comment: @Mangu otherwise for the service account I am using it has the following roles :CloudFunctions.ServiceAgent , is this enough, in all cases I can't change roles because we have a dedicted admin gor the GCP platform

Comment: The `CloudFunctions.ServiceAgent` role is for another service account in your project. Ask the admin to grant Developer and Service Account User to the Circle CI service account.

Comment: Take care to use `apt-get install google-cloud-sdk`, as this will install old versions (for me it'll install v201, while the current one is v212). It might be worth checking this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-versioned-archives), specific for using gcloud with CI tools.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the [roles](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/iam#troubleshooting_permission_errors) that your user and the Service Account have assigned.